# Fade out and translate VectorDrawable with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to get an AnimatedVectorDrawable to fade out and translate at the same time. I made an `ObjectAnimator` resource:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="translationX"
    android:duration="@+string/animtime"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="150"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:duration="@+string/animtime"
    android:valueFrom="255"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="intType"/>
```

Then targeted a `VectorDrawable` with the `ObjectAnimation`:

```
<target
    android:name="disgust"
    android:animation="@anim/fadetransout" />
```

The `VectorDrawable` is a `<group>` in a `VectorDrawable` resource file.

But when I start the animation nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

I found this in the stack trace:

```
Method setTranslationX() with type float not found on target class class android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VGroup
Method setAlpha() with type int not found on target class class android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VGroup
```

Does it have something to do with this?

If this isn't possible, is there another way I can get my `VectorDrawable` to fade and translate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found out what I have done wrong. I took a second look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) and realized what the problem was. What I didn't say, and didn't think mattered was that the `disgust` drawable is a `<group>` and `<group>` does have an x translation attribute but it's called `translateX`, so that's the first thing that I got wrong.

The second thing is that the attribute `alpha` is for the entire `<vector>` which is the "parent" of `<group>`. What I actually wanted was something to change the alpha of a `<path>`. This is done by using the attribute `fillAlpha`. `fillAlpha` is a float that goes from `0` to `1`. `0` being transparent and `1` being opaque. `0` to `255` means it fades in 255 times in the duration.

The lastly, these two `objectAnimator`s cannot be together in the same XML file, since one is for a `<group>` and one is for a `<path>`. So the final result is this:

In a file called `translate_out.xml` I now have,

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="translateX"
        android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="150" />
</set>
```

And in another file called `fade_out.xml` I now have,

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0" />
</set>
```

And finally in `vectordrawable.xml` I have,

```
<target
    android:name="disgust_path"
    android:animation="@anim/fade_out" />
<target
    android:name="disgust"
    android:animation="@anim/translate_out" />
```

where `disgust_path` is now a path a I have named that was always inside the `disgust` group.

I have moved the animation time string to `integers.xml` and called it `animation_duration`.